# How to get device contact number list from Jquery PhoneGap app

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am trying to create a contact retrieving form in my Jquery mobile - phoneGap app. What i wanted to do is search for contact by name and place the number of the result contact into another input field. i have worked on this since yesterday but still could not make it work. --- Phonegap version 2.9.0

This is my code

```
$('#findContactBtn').click(function(){

var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";      
options.multiple = true;  

filter = $('#nameField').value(), 

navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options); 

 })

function onSuccess(contacts) {
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
//return the result number here
$('#messageNumber').attr('value', contact[0].phoneNumbers[0].value);

 }
};


 function onError(contactError) {
alert('onError!');
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="content">

 <label for="nameField">Search Contact</label>
  <input type="search" name="nameField" id="nameField" value=""  />
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="findContactBtn" />


  <label for="messageNumber">Number:</label>
  <input type="tel" name="messageNumber" id="messageNumber" value=""  />

  </div>
```

I will really really glad if anyone can be of help, Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [having difficulty retrieving device contact in Jquery - PhoneGap app (android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214573/having-difficulty-retrieving-device-contact-in-jquery-phonegap-app-android)

Comment: https://github.com/macdonst/TelephoneNumberPlugin

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Thank you, The thing is i am not really good in javascripts. so if you have use the plugin before you can give me a sample code or point me to the right direction, i will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

First of all install the plugin
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts

than go to the page you need list and write this code

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);



     function onDeviceReady() {

           var options = new ContactFindOptions();
           options.filter="";
           options.multiple=true;
           var fields = ["*"];
          navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
        }
        //on success handler
        function onSuccess(contacts)
        {
           for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
            {
              $("#contactList").append("<li>"+contacts[i].phoneNumber[0].value+"</li>");
              $("#contactList").listview("refresh");
            }
        }
    //error handler
        function onError()
        {
          alert("Some Error Occured");
        }

 </code>
```